# how to extract information from dataframe column and create a new column based on information

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have pandas dataframe which includes list of url like this:

```
api
https://apis.us/image/
https://apis.emea/video/
https://apis.asia/docs/
https://apis.general/
```

I want get a new column `region` which will tell the corresponding region of the urls, in case there is no region in the url, mark that as `global`.

```
api                         region
https://apis.us/image/      us
https://apis.emea/video/    emea
https://apis.asia/docs/     asia
https://apis.general/       global
```

How can I achieve this in efficient way? For all urls I have to search with this three region `us, emea and asia`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need test values after `apis.` text use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with first a positive lookbehind with joined possible values in list with replace not matched values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
vals = ['us','emea','asia']
df['region'] = (df['api'].str.extract(rf'(?<=https://apis\.)({"|".join(vals)})')
                         .fillna('global'))

print (df)
                        api  region
0    https://apis.us/image/      us
1  https://apis.emea/video/    emea
2   https://apis.asia/docs/    asia
3     https://apis.general/  global
```

If need test any substring:

```
vals = ['us','emea','asia']
df['region'] = df['api'].str.extract(rf'({"|".join(vals)})').fillna('global')
```